# Let's do some “enciph5r47g”

Tags: c#, .net

I implemented the enciphering/deciphering algorithm from [this code golf task](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115742/lets-do-some-enciph5r47g).

- Enciphering reads string from left to right, replacing each character
  by a number N (0-9) to indicate that it is the same as the character
  N+1 positions before it.
- Only characters up to 10 positions back are
  replaced.
- Deciphering inverses the procedure.
- An unciphered string to be enciphered must contain
  characters in the range 32-126 and no digits (0-9).
- An enciphered string must contain only characters in the range 32-126.

#### Cipher class

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Enciph5r47g {
    public static class Cipher {
        public static string Encipher(string str) {
            CheckStringThrowException(str, IsEnciphered: false);

            string encStr = string.Empty;

            // For every character c in unciphered string...
            for (int index = 0; index<str.Length; index++) {
                char c = str[index];
                char digit = FirstDigit;
                bool digitIsUsed = false;

                // ...check its previous characters from right to left (so long as we are within available digits).
                for (int backIndex=index-1; (backIndex >= 0) && (digit <= LastDigit); backIndex--) {
                    // If a character matches c, add a digit in place of c in encoded string.
                    if (str[backIndex] == c) {
                        encStr = encStr + digit;
                        digitIsUsed = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    digit++;
                }

                // If no character matched c, add the original character in encoded string.
                if (!digitIsUsed)
                    encStr = encStr + c;
            }

            AssertCheckString(encStr, IsEnciphered: true);
            return encStr;
        }

        public static string Decipher(string str) {
            CheckStringThrowException(str, IsEnciphered: true);

            string decStr = string.Empty;

            // For every character c in enciphered string...
            for (int index = 0; index<str.Length; index++) {
                char c = str[index];

                // ...if not a digit, add it in deciphered string...
                if (!char.IsDigit(c)) {
                    decStr = decStr + c;
                    continue;
                }

                // ...else go to the character the digit is referring...
                int backIndex = index - ((int)c - (int)FirstDigit + 1);
                if (backIndex < 0)
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                        "Invalid digit '{0}' in position {1} in enciphered string '{2}'", c, index, str));
                // ...and add this character in deciphered string.
                decStr = decStr + decStr[backIndex];
            }

            AssertCheckString(decStr, IsEnciphered: true);
            return decStr;
        }


        private static readonly char FirstDigit = '0';
        private static readonly char LastDigit = '9';

        #region "Cipherstring validation"

        private static void CheckStringThrowException(string s, bool IsEnciphered) {
            string msg = CheckString(s, IsEnciphered);
            if (msg != string.Empty)
                throw new ArgumentException(msg);
        }

        private static void AssertCheckString(string s, bool IsEnciphered) {
            string msg = CheckString(s, IsEnciphered);
            Debug.Assert(msg == string.Empty);
        }

        /// <returns>A message describing the error in s, or empty string for no error.</returns>
        private static string CheckString(string s, bool IsEnciphered) {
            string stringDescr = IsEnciphered ? "Enciphered" : "Deciphered"; 

            char ch = s.ToCharArray().FirstOrDefault((c) => !IsAllowed(c));
            if (ch != char.MinValue)
                return string.Format("{0} string '{1}' contains unallowed character '{2}'", 
                    stringDescr, s, ch.ToString());

            if (!IsEnciphered) {
                ch = s.ToCharArray().FirstOrDefault((c) => char.IsDigit(c));
                if (ch != char.MinValue)
                    return string.Format("{0} string '{1}' contains digit '{2}'", 
                        stringDescr, s, ch.ToString());
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        private static bool IsAllowed(char c) => 32 <= c && c <= 126;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

#### Class CipherPair

```
namespace Enciph5r47g.Test {
    internal struct CipherPair {
        public CipherPair(string dec, string enc) {
            DecipheredValue = dec;
            EncipheredValue = enc;
        }

        public string DecipheredValue { get; private set; }
        public string EncipheredValue { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

#### Class CipherTest

```
using Enciph5r47g;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace Enciph5r47g.Test {
    [TestClass]
    public class CipherTest {
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        [TestMethod]
        public void EncipherInvalidString() {
            string enciphered = Cipher.Encipher(InvalidCipherString);
        }

        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        [TestMethod]
        public void EncipherInvalidStringWithDigit() {
            string enciphered = Cipher.Encipher(InvalidDecipheredStringWithDigit);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Encipher() {
            foreach (CipherPair pair in TestData) {
                string enciphered = Cipher.Encipher(pair.DecipheredValue);
                Assert.AreEqual(pair.EncipheredValue, enciphered, "Enciphering('{0}').", pair.DecipheredValue);
            }
        }


        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        [TestMethod]
        public void DecipherInvalidString() {
            string deciphered = Cipher.Decipher(InvalidCipherString);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void DecipherInvalidEncipheredString() {
            foreach (string s in InvalidEncipheredStrings) {
                try {
                    string deciphered = Cipher.Decipher(s);
                    Assert.Fail("Deciphering invalid enciphered string '{0}' did not throw expected exception.", s);
                } catch (ArgumentException) {
                    // Expected exception thrown, no action necessary.
                }
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void DecipherTest() {
            foreach (CipherPair pair in TestData) {
                string deciphered = Cipher.Decipher(pair.EncipheredValue);
                Assert.AreEqual(pair.DecipheredValue, deciphered, "Deciphering('{0}').", pair.EncipheredValue);
            }
        }


        private static readonly string InvalidCipherString = ((char)127).ToString();
        private static readonly string InvalidDecipheredStringWithDigit = ('0').ToString();

        private string[] InvalidEncipheredStrings = new string[] {
            "0",
            "a1",
        };

        private CipherPair[] TestData = new CipherPair[] {
            new CipherPair("abcd", 
                           "abcd"),
            new CipherPair("aaaa", 
                           "a000"),
            new CipherPair("banana", 
                           "ban111"),
            new CipherPair("Hello World!", 
                           "Hel0o W2r5d!"),
            new CipherPair("this is a test", 
                           "this 222a19e52"),
            new CipherPair("golfing is good for you", 
                           "golfin5 3s24o0d4f3r3y3u"),
            new CipherPair("Programming Puzzles & Code Golf", 
                           "Prog2am0in6 Puz0les7&1Cod74G4lf"),
            new CipherPair("Replicants are like any other machine. They're either a benefit or a hazard.", 
                           "Replicants 4re3lik448ny3oth8r5mac6in8.8T64y'r371it9376a1b5n1fit7or2a1h2z17d."),
        };
    }
}
```

Would be happy to hear your comments.

Comment: A brief description is already in <summary> comment of the Cipher class. I felt that putting a similar one in the question would be duplicating. If one needs complete information, one anyway needs to click the link for the golf task. Is this reasoning incorrect?

Answer (score 6):

Code style:

1. Normally you put braces on new line in C#.
2. Method parameters should use camel case: `IsEnciphered` => `isEnciphered`
3. You have inconsistent spacing between operators: `backIndex >= 0` but `index<str.Length`, for example. The former is better.

Refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2005/01/26/internal-coding-guidelines/) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) for other common guidelines.

---

> ```
>         char ch = s.ToCharArray().FirstOrDefault((c) => !IsAllowed(c));
>         if (ch != char.MinValue)
> ```

This will probably fail if original string contains `char.MinValue`, producing a false-positive validation.

---

> ```
> private static string CheckString(string s, bool IsEnciphered)
> ```

I would rather have two separate methods: one to check input and one to check output. Having a flag for that looks messy and scales poorly.

---

You can replace some of your loops with LINQ. For example, from what I can see this:

> ```
>             char digit = FirstDigit;
>             bool digitIsUsed = false;
>
>             // ...check its previous characters from right to left (so long as we are within available digits).
>             for (int backIndex=index-1; (backIndex >= 0) && (digit <= LastDigit); backIndex--) {
>                 // If a character matches c, add a digit in place of c in encoded string.
>                 if (str[backIndex] == c) {
>                     encStr = encStr + digit;
>                     digitIsUsed = true;
>                     break;
>                 }
>                 digit++;
>             }
>
>             // If no character matched c, add the original character in encoded string.
>             if (!digitIsUsed)
>                 encStr = encStr + c;
> ```

is probably equivalent to this ([IndexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2471631/1386995)):

```
var digit = str.Reverse().Skip(str.Length - index).Take(10).IndexOf(c);
encStr += digit < 0 ? c.ToString() : digit.ToString();
```

I didn't have a chance to test it though ^^. This can be further optimized, if you reverse input string before entering outer loop. Then you can just use  `str.Skip(index)` instead of `str.Reverse().Skip(str.Length - index)`. You can also replace outer loop with `Enumerable.Select`. LINQ-based solution will not be as fast as loop-based one for obvious reasons, but it should be a lot shorter and probably better in terms of readability.

The same thing can be done to decoding.

---

Probably not that important, since you are code-golfing, but I think there is no reason for `Cipher` to be static. Non-static class would be more useful. By that I mean that you can't really extend or swap out (in LSP-sense) a static class. If `Cipher` was a part of larger software I would recommend defining a contract, say:

```
interface ICipher 
{
    string Encipher(string str);
    string Decipher(string str);
}
```

and replacing

> ```
> public static class Cipher
> ```

with

```
public class Cipher : ICipher
```

Then you would be able to extend or change encoding strategy implementation if needed without any hassle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! BTW, I am not really code-golfing (just picked up my topic from there). I do not aim for shortness, just for best design/implementation.

Comment: I interpret your comment that it would make more sense to have the Cipher class non static and keep information of the enciphered/deciphered string (e.g. Constructor with either the enciphered or the deciphered string) and be able to reference both as properties. Did I interpret correctly?

Comment: @Manolis, I elaborated on my last point.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> private static void CheckStringThrowException(string s, bool IsEnciphered)
> {
>   string msg = CheckString(s, IsEnciphered);
>   if (msg != string.Empty)
>       throw new ArgumentException(msg);
> }
> ```

- I find you should have two methods validating a string. One for each case.
- The name `CheckString` is a really bad name. I needed quite some time to figure out what's going on here only to discover that it does not only check the string but also creates an error message! These two responsibilities need to be separated e.g.

```
void ValidateDecipheredString(string text) {...} 

void ValidateEncipheredString(string text) {...}
```

Each of those method could already throw an exception with the appropriate message.

---

> ```
> private static void AssertCheckString(string s, bool IsEnciphered)
> {
>   string msg = CheckString(s, IsEnciphered);
>   Debug.Assert(msg == string.Empty);
> }
> ```

The name `Assert` in this method suggests it's only for debugging but it's not decorated with the `ConditionalAttribute`. Don't you actually write tests for this purpose? I find this method is unnecessary.